# three.js mesh rendering too slow

Tags: three.js

I have three layers (Object3D) each has about 20K sphere geometries. The rendering is making the whole browser stuck. Is there any way for faster rendering of these objects? As few other answers on SO, I am using same geometry and re-using three materials created only once. Also, these are dynamic objects and cannot use pre-generated json. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you used instancing? Here is an example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_billboards

Comment: I will try and let you know how goes.

Answer (score 1):

It’s slowing down because of the overhead involved when drawing each sphere.

Instancing here helps by reducing both the drawcall overhead and potentially removing nodes for the matrix updates.

Thee.js has a low level interface that does not work on the scene level.

You can try this 3rd part module https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-instanced-mesh

Comment: Looks promising, will give it a try. Do you know of any other alternative to spheres? I am trying to draw a graph of nodes and edges which also supports raycaster. The nodes just needs to be small balls.

Comment: im not sure if i understand the question? Note that with instancing you will actually havea  probelm raycasting. But you probably don't want to raycast against a sphere mesh anyway. I'd suggest having one structure for the cpu side "world" (you can raycast against just spheres not meshes), and another one, instanced that renders stuff gpu side efficiently.